# When falling asleep does one always start with NREM1?

Tags: sleep

After my admittedly short research I could not find information which states that if a person is disturbed while their sleeping, let's say in NREM3 phase of their sleep cycle, and wakes up and then falls asleep shortly after then they start their cycle from scratch again.

It's a widely accepted, and experienced, that being disturbed doesn't make it a good night sleep, but is it because of this 'not picking up where you stopped'?

Could you point me to some data about this?